# How to extract metadata and structure from Fireworks PNG files for conversion?

Tags: svg, reverse-engineering, file-format, fireworks

Since Adobe has declared Fireworks dead, it is apparent that many of us are potentially locked into Fireworks in terms of the proprietary layered PNG format that they have used.  I have been hunting for options to extract / convert my documents over to either PSD's or some other layered SVG structure (perhaps similar to what `Sketch` does on OS X).

Anyone have any ideas for extracting the contents of Fireworks' PNGs programmatically?  So far I haven't seen any libraries to make this feasible and really no discussion of how the metadata is structured in a Fireworks PNG in a format that would help to reverse engineer this format for proper conversion and extraction.

Comment: Without seeing some sample files, it's difficult to answer.